# Customers on Admin not showing and producing an error after migration

Tags: magento2, migration

**After completing the migration from Magento 1.14.4.2 to 2.3.2 we get an error** 
"There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

> Error log record number: 1069290760737" and when we view the error in
>   the  report this is what it says

**{ 0 : Missing required argument $options of Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config. , 1 :#1 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]....**

Answer (score 1):

Please go to file: **var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Config.php**

Then change public function **_construct(array $options)** to public function **_construct($options)**

Comment: Hello @litExtension.Thanks for the response however,that file doesn't exist under Model. This is magento2 version 2.3.2. Is that the same version you where talking about and could it be another file that you meant to point out?

Comment: @Mona Sorry, my mistake! please go to this right file: vendor/module_eav/Model/Entity/Source/Config.php. Then follow my previous instruction. Does it work?